# Parse correct datetime using Python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So I have two spreadsheets in csv format that I've been provided with for my masters uni course.

Part of the processing of the data involved the merging of the files, followed by running some reports off the merged content using dates. this I've completed successfully, however....

The current date format I'm led to believe is epoch so for example the first date on the spreadsheet is 43471

So, firstly I ran this code first to check what format it was looking at

```
pd.read_csv('bookloans_merged.csv')
df.info()
```

This returned the result

```
 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1958 entries, 0 to 1957
Data columns (total 9 columns):
 #   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------          --------------  ----- 
 0   Number          1958 non-null   int64 
 1   Title           1958 non-null   object
 2   Author          1854 non-null   object
 3   Genre           1958 non-null   object
 4   SubGenre        1958 non-null   object
 5   Publisher       1845 non-null   object
 6   member_number   1958 non-null   int64 
 7   date_of_loan    1958 non-null   int64 
 8   date_of_return  1958 non-null   int64 
dtypes: int64(4), object(5)
memory usage: 137.8+ KB
```

I then ran the following code:

```
  # parsing date values

df = pd.read_csv('bookloans_merged.csv')

df[['date_of_loan','date_of_return']] = df[['date_of_loan','date_of_return']].apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

df.to_csv('bookloans_merged_dates.csv', index=False)
```

Running this again:

```
pd.read_csv('bookloans_merged_dates.csv')
df.info()
```

I get:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1958 entries, 0 to 1957
Data columns (total 9 columns):
 #   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------          --------------  -----         
 0   Number          1958 non-null   int64         
 1   Title           1958 non-null   object        
 2   Author          1854 non-null   object        
 3   Genre           1958 non-null   object        
 4   SubGenre        1958 non-null   object        
 5   Publisher       1845 non-null   object        
 6   member_number   1958 non-null   int64         
 7   date_of_loan    1958 non-null   datetime64[ns]
 8   date_of_return  1958 non-null   datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), int64(2), object(5)
memory usage: 137.8+ KB
```

So I can see the date_of_loan and date_of_return is now datetime64

trouble is, all the dates are now showing as 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000043471

How do I get to 01/03/2019 format please?

Thanks

David.

Comment: Could you provide a link to `bookloans_merged.csv` or at least a subset of that CSV?

Comment: Sure here it is on my github I've put them both up bookloans_merged.csv and bookloans_merged_dates.csv here https://github.com/d212digital/MachineLearning---Python

Comment: Any joy on this at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to get this figured out, with a little help. Here is the answer

from datetime import datetime

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_frame, columns=['Title','Author','date_of_loan'])

df1['date_of_loan'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date_of_loan'], unit='d', origin=pd.Timestamp('1900-01-01'))

df1.sort_values('date_of_loan', ascending=True)

```
from datetime import datetime

excel_date = 43139
d_time = datetime.fromordinal(datetime(1900, 1, 1).toordinal() + excel_date - 2)
t_time = d_time.timetuple()
print(d_time)
print(t_time)
```

So how I was able to use that premise in my program was like this

```
from datetime import datetime

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_frame, columns=['Title','Author','date_of_loan'])

df1['date_of_loan'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date_of_loan'], unit='d', origin=pd.Timestamp('1900-01-01'))

df1.sort_values('date_of_loan', ascending=True)
```