# Add list data to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have a dictionary

```
dict={'Andrew':5, 'Brian':3, 'Clive':2, 'David':4}
```

it contains the names of volunteers and the number of times that they have volunteered for a particular duty. The dictionary is regularly updated by providing both the dictionary and a list to a function upd.

For the current update the following list has been declared - each name represents a new volunteer session:

```
ulist = ['Brian', 'David', 'Peter']
```

Write and demonstrate the function upd. Any ideas where to start

I have

```
def upd(lst):
```

I know its not much, but I am just learning about lists and dictionaries.

TIA

David.

EDIT:

My apologies, I should have been more specific

the upd function should create the dictionary and append/increment when a user is found, if not, it should create new user

Comment: What is `udp` supposed to do?

Comment: I'm having to make inferences about what you are asking, so you should update the question to explain exactly what the `udp` function is supposed to do. I'm guessing it updates your dictionary. If a name in `ulist` is already in the dictionary, increment the value associated with it, otherwise create an entry for the name and initialize the value to 1. Is this correct?

Comment: My apologies, I should have been more specific

the upd function should create the dictionary and append/increment when a user is found, if not, it should create new user

Comment: Here's a hint: Try using `dict.get("name", 0)`

Also, you don't want to name a variable `dict` in python as it is already a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I imagine your requirements are:

> If a name in ulist is already in the dictionary, increment the value associated with it, otherwise create an entry for the name and initialize the value to 1.

This code is quite simple really. Just iterate through each name in `ulist` and check to see if it is in `my_dictionary`, if not then add it, if so then increment it.

```
my_dictionary = {'Andrew':5, 'Brian':3, 'Clive':2, 'David':4}
ulist = ['Brian', 'David', 'Peter']

def udp(lst):
    for name in lst:
        if name in my_dictionary:
            my_dictionary[name] += 1
        else:
            my_dictionary[name] = 1

udp(ulist)
print(my_dictionary)
```

Results:

```
{'Andrew': 5, 'Brian': 4, 'Clive': 2, 'David': 5, 'Peter': 1}
```

Note: You named your dictionary `dict` which is technically a keyword in Python so I recommend changing it to something like `my_dictionary` as shown in my example.

Comment: Ah yes I didn't mean to type dict=

Comment: thanks again for your help, maybe you could take a look at my other issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69316653/parse-correct-datetime-using-python-and-pandas